# Website for showing upstream dependencies for Noetic release?

Tags: ros, meta, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I know I saw it somewhere but I can't seem to find it now.  Where is the web tool that shows what the upstream dependencies are for a specific ros release.  I'm working on a Noetic release of several packages and I'm trying to figure out if all my upstream dependencies have been released and what versions they are.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359953/website-for-showing-upstream-dependencies-for-noetic-release?/) by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2020-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably what you are thinking of: [status_page/blocked_releases_noetic.html](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/blocked_releases_noetic.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2